# Is CE_image compatible with EE version 5?

Tags: ce-image

Updated to version 5 of ExpressionEngine, and CE_image has seemed to stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CE_image 3.0.1 works on EE5 installations, but pre-dates the release of EE4/5 by some time, so it is quite possible that it does not work so well with aspects of EE that were changed or introduced in these newer versions.

If you post some more details about what issues you are having, and the versions of EE and CE_Image you are using, it might be possible for others to give you some guidance about how to get it working.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it and seems to work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work for you because I have used latest version of **CE Image** in couple of websites. And it works like a charm.